# Denoising Animations

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

on November 2018 Brecht und Lukas Stockner introduced a way to Denoise an animation after it is rendered. They are using more than one frame to produce a flicker free image.

https://developer.blender.org/D3889

Does anyone know how this works or could provide an Manual?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the **Denoise** node in the *Compositor*.

https://cgcookie.com/tutorial/denoising-renders-in-blender-2-81

https://developer.blender.org/D4304

Comment: Hallo Tareyes, no i don't talking about the node. I am talking about "the old denoiser" and his ability to denoise EXR Files after they have rendered.

Comment: From what I understood, the denoiser update is a Python API function/procedure that allows you to denoise an animation after the render took place. If you want to use Python, the functions are in the link you posted, if you want to to it in the GUI the compositor is the way to do it (the old denoiser in the properties tab is only affecting single images during renders, so can't denoise multiple frames, so that update was probably used in the node)

Comment: cgcookie link has expired