# Denoising the frames of an animation

Tags: animation, denoise

I would like to use the new denoise node in Blender 2.81 to denoise an animation. I understand how to denoise (in compositing) individual frames but I do not know how to run the denoiser for all frames of the animation. Maybe this is a related question:

[Denoising Animations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156407/denoising-animations)

but I still do not understand how to denoise all the frames of animation. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the denoiser in inserted in compositor between render layer and composite node, and "compositing" is checked in post processing tab (as default), every frame of the animation will be automatically processed.

[image]