# Rendered denoised animation

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

So I rendered the animation png sequence, then I plugged the render results into the denoiser node and then in the composite node. But it only denoise the last frame of animation. How can I actually get the rendered png seq denoised? [image]?

Comment: Have you checked "compositing" in post processing tab.
[Check This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162955/denoising-the-frames-of-an-animation?rq=1)

Comment: You have to use an image node to load the sequence back in... To make the denoiser working properly you also have to plug in the albedo pass as well as the normal pass... also never ever render to png. Render to exr multilayer and enable albedo (diff dir) and normal or just the denoise passes if you want to denoise in a second step.

Comment: [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173760/31447), [Can't Get New Intel Denoiser to Work on Projects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163160/31447)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173760/how-to-properly-connect-the-denoise-node-in-compositor)